# Excel VBA - Sum between two values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report where I'm trying to get the sum of a dynamic number of rows in order to produce a subtotal.

```
If Cells(s, 1).Value = "start" Then
   If Cells(r, 1).Value = "subtotal" Then
    'Set the Monthly Subtotal Formulas
     Cells(r, 44) = "=SUM(AR" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":AR" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     Cells(r, 46) = "=SUM(AT" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":AT" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
    'Set the Weekly Subtotal Formulas
     Cells(r, 48) = "=SUM(AV" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":AV" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     Cells(r, 52) = "=SUM(AZ" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":AZ" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     'Set the Daily Subtotal Formulas
     Cells(r, 54) = "=SUM(BB" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":BB" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     Cells(r, 56) = "=SUM(BD" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":BD" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     'Set the Hourly Formulas
     Cells(r, 60) = "=SUM(BH" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":BH" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     Cells(r, 62) = "=SUM(BJ" & Trim(Str(s)) & ":BJ" & Trim(Str(r - 1)) & ")"
     Cells(r, 1) = ""
    End If
    Cells(s, 1) = ""
End If
```

Basically, each work group is within the cell values "start" and "subtotal".
How can I find the 's' or row number and use that in the formula?

Comment: Are you just trying to find each instance of "Start" and "Subtotal" on each sheet, and process the formulas for each block? If so, see .Find and .FindNext methods.

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of your data? There might be an easier way?

Comment: what was wrong about the [built-in subtotals](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-subtotals-HP005200946.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'm trying to do. I'm not too familiar with VBA, so I'll take a look into those methods.

Thanks!

Comment: @deathApril: + 1 You have hit the nail on the head. Exactly my thoughts... :)

Comment: This needs to be something that the persons generating the report will not have to do themselves as the reports can contain large amounts of data needed to be totaled

Comment: @PlatiNUM see my answer if it is what you need - if not, please rephrase your question

Comment: @PlatiNUM: If you want you can still use the inbuilt subtotal in VBA even for dynamic range. If you can show a sample of the data then I can show you a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the time, **[built-in subtotals feature of Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-subtotals-HP005200946.aspx)** should be sufficient

---

in case you really need to use VBA solution and don't know how to iterate it over all "subtotal" tags already present in the data, place your code inside a loop like this:

```
header_column = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Value2
s = 1
For r = 1 To UBound(header_column)
    If header_column(r, 1) = "start" Then
        s = r
    End If
    If header_column(r, 1) = "subtotal" Then
        ' ... do your stuff here ... '
        ' s = r ' if the next "start" tag always follows a subtotal tag, no need for the "start" tags at all, just uncomment this line just before End If
    End If
Next
```

P.S.: no need for `"string" & Trim(Str(integer))`, use `"string" & integer` instead